# How to reshape this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe where words took the place of default row numbers (1,2,3, etc.):

```
                       Score
commitment            -0.9843452
progress              -0.9831530
implement             -0.9785868
decision              -0.9777243
message               -0.9762919
deficit               -0.9752300
invest                0.9929340
multiplier            0.9940889
fiscal_capacity       0.9940889
public_investment     0.9949193
aggregate_demand      0.9955452
space                 0.9960338
```

I want to achieve two things: 1) the "column" of words to become a proper column (the second column of the dataframe); 2) keep only those words that have a score bigger or equal 0. I tried a lot of solution but I failed. Unfortunately, I don't know how to create a dfm with words instead of numbers so I can't provide you with code (I derived it from list in my real-life scenario).

Is there anyone who can help me with that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R`.  Create a `data.frame` from the row names of the dataset and `subset` the rows based on the values of 'Score'

```
subset(data.frame(newcol = row.names(df1), Score = df1$Score), Score >=0)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'newcol')  %>%
     filter(Score >= 0)
```

Comment: Both answers work perfectly. Very efficient and nice codes. Thanks so much!

Comment: just waiting the technical time. I couldn't accept it before